# HTML input type=“file” in iframe breaks the file select dialog in Chrome and Edge

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, iframe, chromium, input-type-file

I'm working on a React web app that has an `iframe` component to embed another web app. The parent app has functions to open or close (unmount) the iframe component. And the parent app uses real-time data subscription and it has the behavior to automatically close the iframe when it got a specific event. So it means that the iframe can be closed anytime.

Now onto the problem, both of the apps have `input type="file"` to upload file. If the iframe got unmounted while I have a "file select dialog" opened from within the iframe, the dialog would still be displayed unless I click the "cancel" button. But the thing is, after closing the file dialog and click `Choose File` in another `input type="file"`, the file dialog will never show up again unless I refresh the page.

For more info:

- the bug won't happen if I run any of the parent or iframe app in localhost, it only happen on the deployed site
- Both of the apps is from same domain but with different pathname (ex. `https://hello.com/parent` and `https://hello.com/iframe`)

I'm not sure if this is a Chromium bug because it happens in Google Chrome and MS Edge, but not in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Can repro here: https://jsfiddle.net/opfwLa7v/ on macOs BigSur. Yes this is a chromium bug, you can file an issue at https://crbug.com/new

Comment: @Kaiido thank you! Also, I tested on both macOs BigSur and on Windows 10 and it has the same issue.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1244396